# Android contacts - missing ME contact

Tags: contacts

I'm a new android user. Yesterday I was adding a bunch of contacts to my phone and I could see the ME contact listed on top in the Contacts app. I opened up the contacts app this morning and the ME contact was gone. Can someone tell me why it's missing and how can I add it back (other than recreating it in the form of a new contact named "AAAA")

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please mention your **Android version** and whether you have a **hardware menu button or not**

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I'm using Android 6.0.1 and I don't believe I have a hardware menu button (the phone is Nexus 5X)

Comment: I have the same problem. Recently upgraded to android 6.0.1 and the ME contact at the top of the contacts is gone. I mean, who the hell knows their own phone number, the one number you never call. Further more, I'm not listed at all! Where's the ME contact?

Answer (score 1):

Found it!

I opened up Contacts, then went into Settings. At the top of this list I have 'My info', which contains the 'Me' contact.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: I don't have a "My Info" section in there :(